# NetLogo get each time different random number from certain list

Tags: random, netlogo

let's say I have list

```
let mylist [0 1 2 3]
```

and I would like to generate random number from this array which is in every tick different than previous one.

Example: Tick one - generates 0
         Tick two - generates 2
         Tick three - generates 1
         Tick four - generates 3

Now I have

```
let mylist [0 1 2 3]
let x one-of mylist
```

But that returns for example for two consecutive ticks number 0.

Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to store the number that was used in the last tick, compare it to the one chosen in the current tick, and choose a different one if they are the same.

```
globals [
  previous_number
]

to generate  

  let current_number previous_number
  let mylist [ 0 1 2 ]
  while [ current_number = previous_number ] [
    set current_number one-of mylist
  ]
  set previous_number current_number
  print current_number

end
```